# Is there an nginx variable that can be used to get some or all of the directories in path?

Tags: nginx

As the title says; what I'd really like to get from an nginx variable is the directory of a requested file.

The reason being that I am handling user-uploaded static content, which is organised into sub-directories by user, and I'd like to place limits on what content such as HTML and Javascript can do from the upload location, without having to disallow them entirely.

For example, I might do something like:

```
set_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src $file_directory";
```

Assuming I had the correct value for the directory, this could mean that if a user uploaded an HTML file and some resources, then modern browsers would only allow the HTML file to reference resources that are placed in the same directory (no linking to another user's directory or an external site).

Ideally I'd like some more granularity than just the current file's directory. For example, if the requested file was `/username/upload1/index.html` then I might restrict resource references to `mydomain.com/username/upload1`, but allow cookies for `mydomain.com/username` (i.e- cookies could be shared between uploads by the same user).

For the security minded; all user-uploaded content is going under its own sub-domain and treating everything as static. I was originally considering per-user sub-domains, but my reverse proxy and certificate authority won't support it (so I'd lose caching and SSL, neither of which I want to lose!)

Comment: What you want is useless, as CSP works on domain basis. You cannot allow or disallow some path, only whole domain.

Comment: This seems to suggest otherwise: http://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#framework-directive-source-list

I realise it may not be widely supported yet, but it should be in future. Hopefully not long followed by sub-origins (essentially sandboxing pages into a directory structure).

Comment: Oh, they are moving so fast. But csp level 3 is not supported by any browser yet. Even level 2 is supported only by chrome and (partially) firefox

Comment: True, does that mean other browser versions will completely ignore my CSP if I provide the path? Back to the question itself though, ignoring the reason for it, would something like the following do what I want: `location ~ /([^/]+)/([^/]+) { add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src $scheme://$server_name/$1/$2"; }`